# How to use an alias of awk with a parameter in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, function, awk, alias

I am trying to create an alias of awk to clip out important column from a row.
For example :

```
$date | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'              
Wed
```

But i want to create an alias of awk with parameter of the number of column like print $1, print $2 etc.

I tried searching on the internet and reached to this :

```
alias kaat="_kaat"              
_kaat() {                  
    awk -F ' ' '{print var}' var="$1"                 
}
```

but this is still not working and is not giving me any output.

Comment: There's really no need for the alias. Just define `kaat () { ... }`.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use positional parameters built in to the shell? For example: `s="one two three"; set -- $s; echo "$2"` returns `two`.

Comment: Frankly i didn't even know there was a `set` command since i am new to Linux and following a mooc. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @ghoti `kaatua() { set -- $($1) ; echo "$2" ; }` is giving output `Jul` on writing `kaatua date 2` as well as on `kaatua date 1` . I don't know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: @ad1998 - in this case, your `$2` is being overwritten when you run `set`. So you need a different way to reach the data. Try indirection: `kaatua() { local f=$2; set -- $($1); echo "${!f}"; }` (Requires bash 4.)

Comment: @ghoti what does `!` signify in `!f`.

Comment: @ad1998, this is in the "Parameter Expansion" section of the bash man page. *If the first character of parameter is an exclamation  point  (!),  and parameter  is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable indirection.
Bash uses the value of the variable  formed  from  the  rest  of parameter  as  the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value
is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value  of  parameter  itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` will print content of that variable whereas `$var` will print content of field based on value of `var`. You can use any expression within `()`, for ex: `$(var+1)`

```
alias kaat="_kaat"              
_kaat() {                  
    awk -F ' ' '{print $var}' var="$1"                 
}
```

sample run

```
$ echo 'foo baz 123' | kaat 2
baz
$ echo 'foo baz 123' | kaat 1
foo
```

You could simplify/improve your function as mentioned in comments:

```
kaat() {
    awk -v var="$1" '{print $var}'
}

# single line version, note the ;
kaat() { awk -v var="$1" '{print $var}' ; }
```

You can also use `cut` here (Note: this is not exactly equivalent, see [awk field splitting summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html#Field-Splitting-Summary))

```
$ alias k='cut -d" " -f'
$ echo 'foo baz 123' | k 1
foo
$ echo 'foo baz 123' | k 2
baz
```

Comment: You should point out that `-F ' '` is useless since that's just setting FS to its default value and that setting `var="$1"` in the arg list after the script is only for when you need to change values between files and for this application the OP should be using `-v var="$1"` at the start of the script instead to avoid a surprise later if/when she tries to print its value from BEGIN.

Comment: And, as pointed out in the comment to the question, there is no benefit to making a function and then an alias for that function - just use the function directly.

Comment: @EdMorton Can u explain in detail what do you mean by "to avoid a surprise later if/when she tries to print its value from BEGIN". Also i am a he. :)

Comment: @ad1998 ... but [no-one knows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet%2C_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog).

Comment: Try `awk -v x='foo' 'BEGIN{print x}'` and then try `awk 'BEGIN{print x}' x='foo'`. See the difference? Variables set after the script are intended for use in the file that follows them and therefore they are not set when the BEGIN section executes. Variables set with `-v` are intended for use across all files and so ARE set when the BEGIN section executes. So, always set variables with `-v` unless you have a specific purpose in mind that requires you to do it some other way, See .http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.